# why isn't getopt working on python 2.7.5 mac os x

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

For some reason, when I pass in an option using the long form, the getopt function isn't recognizing it properly. Any ideas? I've read the documentation here http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html, and it seems it should not do what it's doing.

I'm running python 2.7.5 on mac os x for the record.

```
[user@macbookpro:~] python Script.py test --condition=foo --output-file abc.def
['test', '--condition=foo', '--output-file', 'abc.def']
[]
<type 'list'>

def main(argv):

    try:
        optlist, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], '', ['condition=', 'output-file=', 'testing'])
    except getopt.GetoptError, msg:
        logging.warning(msg)
        return 1

    print args
    print optlist
    print type(optlist)
```

I should be getting the following as stated in the documentation:

> > > optlist
> > >       [('--condition', 'foo'), ('--testing', ''), ('--output-file', 'abc.def')]

Comment: No I did import getopt at the top.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `getopt`? As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/getopt.html) say, right at the top in a big box, "The getopt module is a parser for command line options whose API is designed to be familiar to users of the C getopt() function. Users who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module instead." You're obviously not a `getopt` expert, so why use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation *doesn't* say that you should be getting that. In fact, it explicitly says you shouldn't:

> *Note:* Unlike GNU `getopt()`, after a non-option argument, all further arguments are considered also non-options. This is similar to the way non-GNU Unix systems work.

And if you look at the examples, the non-option arguments come *after* the options on the command line. If you do that, it gives you what you were hoping for:

```
$ python Script.py --condition=foo --output-file abc.def test
['test']
[('--condition', 'foo'), ('--output-file', 'abc.def')]
<type 'list'>
```

But if you do something different from the examples, you get different results from the examples. And the results you get match what the docs say you should.

But really, if you don't understand why putting `test` after the options is different from putting it before the options, you shouldn't be using `getopt` in the first place. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/getopt.html) say in a big box right at the top:

> *Note:* The `getopt` module is a parser for command line options whose API is designed to be familiar to users of the C `getopt()` function. Users who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the `argparse` module instead.

If you really want to learn `getopt`, then read [the POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html). That's what Python is trying to emulate. It does add [GNU-style](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) `--` long arguments, but that doesn't mean it includes all GNU extensions.